# SceneKit – Node with animated skeleton not moving

Tags: swift, scenekit, scnnode

I have a SceneKit app with 2 `.scn` files in the art.scnassets folder. The base `ship.scn` that comes with the project, and a new file `orcIdle.scn` that I added myself.

When I call this code on this ship, it moves it properly:

```
self.myScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!
// Set the scene to the view
let ship = (myScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: false))!
ship.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -5)
self.sceneView.scene = myScene
```

When I call the same code on my orcIdle file, it places the orc exactly at (0,0,0)

```
self.myScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/orcIdle.scn")!
// Set the scene to the view
let orc = (myScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "orcIdle", recursively: false))!
orc.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -5)
self.sceneView.scene = myScene
```

here are screenshots of the file node:

This is the default ship file included in the project by Xcode.
[image]

This is my orcIdle file.

[image]

As you can see, it's the exact same code but 1 moves, and the other doesn't. Also, in the top right corner of the images, i can adjust the Z value there. It works for .ship, but not for .orcIdle.

Is it a scale issue? Any thoughts?

Here's a new screenshot with as much of the scene graph as I can capture.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you must select a **skeleton's top hierarchy** (like `root` node) to move geometry, since its mesh was bound to skeleton. If model's skeleton is considerably deeper in the hierarchy use `.childNodes[x]` subscript syntax to fetch a desired joint.

But a solution based on your `.scn` file is the following – create a `topNode` object and put `root` and `LOD_Group` inside it.

[image]

So your code should look like this:

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/orcIdle.scn")!
    
orc = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "topNode", recursively: true)!
    
orc.position = SCNVector3(0,0,-20)
```

Comment: Adding a new image above with the full hierarchy. I tried calling "LOD_0", "LOD_Group" and "root" and "pelvis" none worked... Do I need to call pelvis, right foot, and right hand?

Comment: The below did not work:


        self.myScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/orcIdle.scn")!
        // Set the scene to the view
        let orc = (myScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "root", recursively: false))!
        orc.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -5)

Comment: I got it to work... I load the file by drag and dropping the .dae file into "entry.scn" this creates a child "orcIdle.scn". If I keep both files, and call "entry.scn" with the node being "orc idle reference" it works.

Comment: Got it to work. I swear I'd tried that before. Thank you for the help.